# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, classcastexception

I have a RecyclerView with a LinearLayout inside. The LinearLayout consists out of 9 buttons. Before some changes I could click the buttons and it didn't crashed. But after I added this code below it gives the error and does not show where it comes from:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

The imports in Adapter:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Added this in the onClickListener:

```
tempTag = (int) v.getTag();
mAdapter.grayButton(tempTag / 9, tempTag % 9);
zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(mAdapter.getText(tempTag).toString());
```

Added this method in the RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
    public void grayButton(int row, int element){
    recycleViewDatas.get(row).setGray(element);
    notifyItemChanged(row);
}
```

Added this code in the onBindViewHolder:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
viewHolder.ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
lp.height = viewHolder.ll.getLayoutParams().height - (int) (viewHolder.buttons.get(j).getLayoutParams().height - recycleViewDatas.get(i).getSize()) + 30;
viewHolder.ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
if(recycleViewDatas.get(i).getGray() == j)
     viewHolder.buttons.get(j).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
else if(recycleViewDatas.get(i).getGray() == -1)
     viewHolder.buttons.get(j).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

This is my ViewHolder:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout ll;
    private ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewHolder(View v, Context context) {
        super(v);

        ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llRecycleView);
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
            buttons.add((Button) ll.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The layout file of the recycleviewdata:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="9"
android:background="@drawable/zeile"
android:id="@+id/llRecycleView">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

...more buttons

The layout of the MainActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@drawable/top">
...some buttons
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/></LinearLayout>
```

I do not understand why the error comes after the update. And the app only crashes on my M9. On the HTC One V it does not crash and all works as expected.
You know the problem? Do you need any more code?

Comment: The problem is stated in the title... You use 2 different LayoutParams, one standard, and one from the v7 support library... Try to use 1 instead... choose the one depending on the further need

Comment: But where do I use 2 different?
In Main and in Adapter I import 
`import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Comment: LinearLayout in ViewHolder, what are you importing?

Comment: For the LinearLayout in ViewHolder? I import `import android.widget.LinearLayout;`

Comment: Where do you call the `LayoutParams`? Can you show that including the imports?

Comment: Look edit above in onBindViewHolder

Comment: What is the parent of your linear layout in the list item layout(viewHolder.ll)?

Comment: The LinearLayout is the parent. Added the layout file above.

Comment: You need to set the immediate parent layout params for any view

Comment: So change the import of 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams' to 'android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams'

Comment: Then the error is that ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.v7...RecyclerView$LayoutParams

Comment: change the RecyclerView$LayoutParams to ViewGroup$LayoutParams, or vice versa

Comment: change import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutParams; to android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams (guessing on the first packaged, but note the last 2, and the `not` v7)

Comment: If I comment out the LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //viewHolder.ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //lp.height = viewHolder.ll.getLayoutParams().height - (int) (viewHolder.buttons.get(j).getLayoutParams().height - recycleViewDatas.get(i).getSize()) + 30;
            //viewHolder.ll.setLayoutParams(lp); in the onBindVIewHolder it does not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

`LayoutParams` is implemented for (almost) all the layouts.
When you set `LayoutParams` on a view, you need to set it with a type of the view's parents. So if you have a `LinearLayout` and you are trying to add a Button, you need to set `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` on the `Button`. The problem in this case is that you don't know the parent type. And by that I mean it can different on different Android versions.

The safe bet is to use the `LayoutParams` from a common class (`ViewGroup`?) since you only set width and height.

Comment: You mean to use: 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);?
Gives me the error:
android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

Comment: What happens if you force the cast?

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem, you can use this

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams =v.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.height= 200;
    v.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need the kotlin version :

```
 with(view.layoutParams){
                width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
 }
```